# Challenges with geoshow in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mapping

I am not having any luck with the geoshow function in `MATLAB`. I am able to get the worldmap to load, but once I use geoshow I get a single color for the map. The matrix shows up fine in imagesc.

> cmap = colormap(jet)
>   worldmap([41 53],[-123 -109])
>   geoshow(demo, cmap, R)

here is the [link](http://www.science.oregonstate.edu/~sprolese/demotif/demo.tif) to the sample file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geoshow.html) says:

geoshow(A,cmap,R) projects and displays an image georeferenced to latitude-longitude through the referencing matrix R. The image is shown as a texturemap on **a zero-elevation surface**.

Could this be the problem?